# How to search for files and directories using a single find command

Tags: command-line, find, grep, windows-search

I am using UnxUtils on Windows and it comes with the find tool. I am using it to search for files and directories. If I wish to search for a file name which contains the word 'Identity', I use the following (for a case insensitive search)

```
find <location> -type f -iname "*Identity*"
```

and the following for searching directory names

```
find <location> -type d -iname "*Identity*"
```

I wish to search for both files and directories using a single command (to replace windows search). Is this possible using find ? Is there any native Windows tool which I can use instead to do a search on the command line ? The Windows commands FIND and FINDSTR are like the Unix grep and do not really help.

**EDIT:**

```
find <location> -iname "*Identity*" -ls
```

Searches for all files and folders in the given location (recursively). The -iname flag for a case insensitive search and the -ls flag to give an ls like output listing enabling us to know the file types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the type specification.

```
find <location> -iname "*Identity*"
```

Comment: Thanks ! Is there any way to indicate that they are directories in the result ?

Comment: Looking at the man page, I noticed I can use the -ls flag for this purpose.